# Saving / Loading array of objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm trying to Save/Load the array of objects to/from a plain .txt file. I know very little about serialization, but I think I have correctly used it to write the Array of objects to a .txt file. The .txt file is completely unreadable (in normal english) when opened separately. Am I writing it to a file correctly? and how do I go about reading it into the program?

```
public class HotelObjects {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Room[] myHotel = new Room[10];
    for (int x = 0; x < myHotel.length; x++) {
    myHotel[x] = new Room();
    }

    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;

    while (roomNum < 11) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter command : ");
        command = input.next();
        command = command.toLowerCase();

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'v') {
            viewCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'a') {
            addCustomers(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            emptyRooms(myHotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 's') {
            storeData(myHotel);
        }

    }
}

private static void viewCustomers(Room hotelRef []) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotelRef[x].getName());
        }
}

private static void addCustomers(Room myHotel[]) {
    String roomName;
    int roomNum;
    System.out.println("Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        roomNum = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum + " :");
        roomName = input.next();
        myHotel[roomNum].setName(roomName);
}

private static void emptyRooms(Room[] myHotel) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++ )
        if (myHotel[x].getName().equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
}

private static void storeData(Room [] myHotel) {
    try{
        FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HotelObjects\\HotelObject.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(myHotel);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException ioe){
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Room class (if needed):

```
public class Room implements Serializable {


private String mainName;
int guestsInRoom;

public Room() {
    mainName = "e";
    System.out.println("made a room ");
}

public void setName(String aName) {
    mainName = aName;
}

public String getName() {
    return mainName;
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write a collection of objects to file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049750/how-can-i-write-a-collection-of-objects-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

Use ObjectInputStream and a cast to load the array back from the file. And you need to flush the stream at the end of writing to it (before closing it).

Answer (score 0):

The result of writing an ObjectOutputStream is supposed to be machine-readable and not human readable. To read it back in, use:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HotelObjects\\HotelObject.dat");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
Hotel hotel = (Hotel) ois.readObject();
```

Comment: When I use that (in a separate a procedure) it keeps causing two errors in the last line in your suggested code saying that 'cannot find symbol'

Comment: Update your question with the new code and traceback when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

The output of an `ObjectOutputStream` is meant to be machine readable therefore it would not necessarily be human readable. When using closeable resources you should aim to use them within a try block prior to Java 1.7 and close the resource in the finally block of that try or if using 1.7+ a try-with-resources statement. This is to ensure that the resource is closed even in the event of an exception being thrown;

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\Ganz\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HotelObjects\\HotelObject.dat";

try (FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(path); ObjectInputStream inputStream= new ObjectInputStream(fileInput)) {

    // Cast the Object returned from the stream to a Hotel object
    Hotel hotel = (Hotel) inputStream.readObject(); 

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   // TODO: Exception handling here   
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // TODO: Exception handling here     
}
```

If you don't feel the default serialized form suits your need then you can create your own. If so look up how to create a custom serialized form.